# Trying to map old URLs with query strings to new URLS can can't get pattern match correct

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

An example of the old URL would be [www.domain.com/helppages/index.aspx?p=secure](http://www.domain.com/helppages/index.aspx?p=secure), or [www.domain.com/helppages/index.aspx?p=some_other_document](http://www.domain.com/helppages/index.aspx?p=some_other_document)

```
<rule name="some_document" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^helppages*$" ignoreCase="true" />
       <conditions>
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="p=some_document" />
       </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.aspx?p=home/foundation/some_document" />
 </rule>
```

So I want to find the /helppages/, read the value after the "p" in the query string and then set a redirect based on that (note it is not a 1:1 old document name to new so I'll probably need several of these rules so that I can map "old_document_1" to "new_document_1" etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="some_document" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^.*(?:helppages/index.aspx).*$" ignoreCase="true" />
   <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
     <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="p=some_document" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.aspx?p=home/foundation/some_document" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
 </rule>
```